# Cannot enable AccessPoint with ESP8266

Tags: wifi, esp8266, access-point, sming

I am using ESP8266 with SMING ver2.1

To enable Access Point, I have the following code in `init()`

```
WifiAccessPoint.enable(true);
WifiAccessPoint.config("TestAP", "", AUTH_OPEN);
```

The above code works fine. However, when I run the code outside of init(), ESP8266 does not become an AP.

Not sure if it is a SMING bug or just my fault. Did someone else encounter the same problem?